# Installing GitLab using Docker gitlab-ce image

Tags: database, postgresql, gitlab

We are beginners in gitlab and want implement gitlab in our company using Docker. I have seen the documentation for installing docker gitlab-ce image and I have installed it in my local desktop, after I have tweaked some changes, now gitlab is running and I can access the gitlab from local host url.

I came to know we can assign volumes to store bare git repositories [ critical data] and logs. But , how can we handle application data , i.e postgresql database . I have seen gitlab environment where they maintain dedicated database where it stores all user info and groups and project info and do the db to db migration during gitlab updates etc. which seems like standard solution.

How do we handle the same standard solution using gitlab docker installation? Did I miss any step , Do I have to intialize the database first and install docker gitlab image and connect the gitlab with database ? Or Can I use the in built database server ? I don’ think using inbuilt database server which comes in bundle is a standard solution for IT company ? Please suggest me

Thank you all for inputs
PRS

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to launch your DB in separate VM from where your gitlab is deployed.
If you're running on a public cloud you can take advantage of managed RDBMS solutions such as AWS RDS to save yourself the trouble of managing the DB yourself.